# Damping velocity with deltaTime?

Tags: actionscript-3, math, game-physics

I'm trying to gradually reduce the velocity of an object, using a "damping" property. After that, I want to move the object's position using the velocity. It looks something like this:

```
velocity.x *= velocity.damping;
velocity.y *= velocity.damping;
x += velocity.x;
y += velocity.y;
```

Couldn't be much simpler than that and it works fine, but here is my problem: I'm using a deltaTime variable, that contains the amount of time (in seconds), that the last update of my game-loop took. Applying the velocity is easy enough:

```
x += velocity.x * deltaTime;
y += velocity.y * deltaTime;
```

But how can I account for the deltaTime when I multiply the damping property? My idea was, to find the displacement in x or y and multiply the deltaTime to that, like this:

```
velocity.x += (velocity.x * velocity.damping - velocity.x) * deltaTime;
velocity.y += (velocity.y * velocity.damping - velocity.y) * deltaTime;
```

Turns out that does not work. I don't really understand why, but I keep getting different results when I test it. If I simply ignore damping or set it to 1.0, everything works, so the problem must be in the last two lines.

Comment: Why are you substracting the velocity in the last code segment?

Comment: (velocity.x * velocity.damping) is the new velocity.x. I subtract the original velocity.x from that, to get the difference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
velocity.x += (velocity.x * velocity.damping - velocity.x) * deltaTime;
```

That means you have a constant acceleration, not damping.

```
velocity.x * (1 - velocity.damping)
```

is the amount by which you decrement the velocity from the current value in one time unit. It is proportional to the current velocity, so in the next time unit, you would decrement the velocity by a smaller amount using the damping factor. But multiplying with `deltaTime`, you subtract the same amount, calculated from the starting value in all of the `deltaTime` time units.

Let's suppose a damping factor of `0.9`, so you decrement the velocity by a tenth in each time unit. If you use the linear formula (multiply with `deltaTime`), after 10 time units your velocity would become 0, and after 11, it would have switched direction. If you go stepwise, starting from an initial velocity of `v_0 = 1`, you'd get

```
v_1 = v_0*0.9 = 0.9
v_2 = v_1*0.9 = 0.81
v_3 = v_2*0.9 = 0.729
v_4 = v_3*0.9 = 0.6561
```

etc., a slower decrease of the velocity. If you unfold the formula for `v_4`, you get

```
v_4 = v_3*0.9 = v_2*0.9*0.9 = v_1*0.9*0.9*0.9 = v_0*0.9*0.9*0.9*0.9 = v_0 * 0.9^4
```

so, generalising, you see that the formula should be

```
velocity.x *= Math.pow(velocity.damping, deltaTime);
```

(Assuming Action Script doesn't differ from ECMA Script in what that function is called.)

Similarly for `velocity.y` of course.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Makes perfect sense! :)